# Is it possible to prevent a database row from being read via Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, locking

I have a simple setup of Hibernate 3.6 and MySQL. I want to find out how locking works. My code is here:

```
package hibernate;
import java.util.*;
import org.hibernate.*;
public class HibernateGames {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //main transaction
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Message loaded = (Message) session.get(Message.class, 21l);
        session.lock(loaded, LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);

        //concurrent transaction
        Session session2 = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx2 = session2.beginTransaction();
        Message loaded2 = (Message) session2.get(Message.class, 21l);
        tx2.commit();
        session2.close();

        //main transaction committed
        Message loadedAtLast = (Message) session.get(Message.class, 21l);
        tx.commit();
        session.close();

        HibernateUtil.shutdown():
    }
}
```

1. As far as I understand there are 2 main types of locks in every database: exclusive and shared. The first one totally blocks all operations with the row, the second one lets other users read or acquire own shared lock from that row. The first one is set by *select.. update* statement, the second one is set by *select .. lock in share mode* or something like this. Is this correct?
2. Does it work in a different way under different isolation levels?
3. My setup doesn't block the concurrent transaction tx2 from reading. Why? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but the article [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/transactions.html#transactions-locking) says that Hibernate will delegate the locking mechanism to DB, so it depends on the isolation level specified on the db. Also,  I do not see the `LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` anywhere. You may try to lock it using `LockMode.UPGRADE` and try to see if it locks.

If you really want to lock the row in the update db operation try to set the isolation to `serializable` in the hibernate configuration.

**Update**: I believe that you are confused with LockMode of `JPA` and `Hibernate`,LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE is jpa thing and it will work with entityManager setup, it may not work with session. try to replace it with lockmode.UPGRADE which is a hibernate static value.